# Возможен двусторонний ssl между браузером и сервером?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, ssl

Наша команда разработала некоторый сервис для внутреннего пользования (backend на c#, frontend на vuejs). Пользователь проходит аутентификацию по логину, паролю, google authentificator коду и получает Bearer токен (подписанный jwt), который в последствии передается в заголовке Authorization. Сейчас задумались над заменой 2fa. В голову приходят два решения:

1. двусторонний ssl
2. U2F (например ubikey)

Первый вариант в приоритете так как по сути получаем подтверждение присутствия пользователя при каждом запросе, а не только при аутентификации как в случае U2F. Возможно ли реализовать двусторонний ssl фронтенда на JavaScript в браузере с backend на C#? 
Клиентский сертификат при этом должен быть с не экспортируемой приватной частью в хранилище сертификатов ОС. Вообще в идеале на usb токене.

Comment: Двухстронний SSL между браузером и сервером называется HTTP over TLS или просто HTTPS.

Comment: Если вам нужна железобетонная авторизация сотрудников, типа многфакторки, можете Google/Microsoft Authenticator (OTP) прикрутить. Мучаться с установкой сертификатов в систему, которые могут у вас украсть вместе с системой, такое себе занятие. С хардварными токенами еще хуже - они просто либо теряются, либо ломаются, либо вообще не работают, либо работают, но не во всех браузерах (да, под каждый тип браузера придется свой плагин писать, который будет дружить с хардварным ключом), в общем так себе затея.

Comment: В общем, здесь задачу на две распилить стоит: 1) надежность канала передачи данных, 2) уверенность в том, что юзер - тот, за кого себя выдает. Первое обеспечивает HTTPS, и если хочется меганадежно, то HTTP/2+TLS1.3 в помощь с самыми надежными алгоритмами шифрования. По второму я уже выше написал.

Comment: @aepot насколько я понимаю https это односторонний ssl, так как в рукопожатии участвует только сертификат сервера (клиент удостоверяется в валидности сервера, но сервер не знает какой именно клиент пришел). разве не так? мы уже прикрутили google authentificator, я об этом писал. но факт в том что при компроментации логина и пароля пользователя, атакующему остается только подобрать OTP, что в целом не является проблемой т.к. значений всего миллион.

Comment: А вы попробуйте его подобрать, я не думаю, что Гугл вот так вот просто вам позволит это сделать, иначе смысл во всем этом мероприятии? Ну или если OTP вводится в ваш сервис авторизации, по позаботьтесь о том, чтобы вас не брутфорсили, а если и начнут, ваша система безопасности должна немедленно принять меры от бана по IP до блокировки аккаунта, который подвергается брутформу с верно введенными кредами. `https это односторонний ssl` нет, не так. Данные шифруются с использованием асинхронного шифрования при передаче в обе стороны. И TLS предназначен для защиты канала, а не для валидации юзера.

Comment: ...И надежнее всего защищены как раз данные, передаваемые от клиента серверу, так как они могут быть расшифрованы только с помощью приватного ключа сервера. Но вам лучше почитать про безопасность HTTPS прежде чем утверждать, что весь интернет - одна большая дыра в безопасности.